# Count occurences of string in output from qstat

Tags: bash, command-line, queue, mingw

I am trying to write a line of shell code that will tell me how many jobs I have in a queue.

The command `qstat` will return a list of jobs with the following attribute Job id, Name, User, Time Use Queue name

The command is labelled `qstat(1B)` in the man page.

My attempt to count how many jobs I have running uses `grep`:

```
grep -c my_username | qstat
```

As I understand it, this should count the number of occurrences of `my_username` in the output from qstat. It doesn't work though. Any ideas where I am going wrong?

Comment: what is the output of your `qstat` command?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are doing it the other way round.  Instead, say:

```
qstat | grep -c my_username
```

The would [pipe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_%28Unix%29) the *output* of `qstat` to `grep`.

Alternatively, you could say (using [Process Substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution)):

```
grep -c my_username <(qstat)
```

Comment: qstat can directly lookup based on username, there is no need to grep.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
qstat -u my_username
```

This will list only your jobs.  Make sure that you are checking the number of slots that each job is using - counting the lines is not the same as determining resource usage!  Maybe something like:

```
qstat -u $user | tail -n+3 | awk '{total = total+ $9}END{print total}'
```